# Deprecation error Pyspark doesn't supports python 2 and 3 prior to 3.6

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was doing a pyspark course and was asked to do hands-on on Hackerrank platform.

Well my code compiled successfully and passed all test cases but got stuck due to Deprecation Error:

> pyspark doesn't supports python 2 and 3 prior to 3.6

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Some packages like pyspark in their most current version depend on features introduced in a recent python release. `Pyspark doesn't supports python 2 and 3 prior to 3.6` means that you need at least Python version 3.6 to run the most up to date version of Pyspark.

Either update your Python installation (see [here](https://realpython.com/installing-python/))

or install an older version of Pyspark (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/#history))